# Issues while converting query from Oracle to PostgreSQL query using XMLTable function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I am trying to convert a oracle query to postgreSQL but not much clarity in documentation for our use case. Below query filter the xml in doc column but when trying to convert to Postgres i am not able achieve the same functionality

```
select  colA, colB, colC from table1
xmltable('//node1/node2[normalize-space(v1/v2/v3[@type=$test_type])=$test_source]'
PASSING table1.doc, 'test_source' as "source", 
'test_type' as "type" COLUMNS colA XMLTYPE PATH '/')
where (colC, colB) in (('test1', 'test2'))
```

as per the documentation provided https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html

I tried to convert the below query but I could not find  proper way to pass the  variable value, I tried below solution but its not working still.
Any help is appreciated.

```
select colA, colB, colC from table1, 
XMLTABLE('//node1/node2[normalize-space(v1/v2/v3[@type=''test_type''])=''test_source'']' 
PASSING table1.doc COLUMNS colA XML PATH '/') 
where (colC, colB) in (('test1', 'test2'))
```

And this query not working in java and giving error as

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"   Position: 146

but not giving any error in PGAdmin Postgresql query console.